# md-datepicker view should display the months only

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

I am working on a project and I have a md-datepicker on it and I want this md-datepicker to show only the months of the year(January, February, and so on ......). How can I do this?

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="currentDate" md-current-view="month" md-date-filter="monthlyDate"></md-datepicker>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("DashboardApp", ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate','md.data.table']);
app.controller('rptController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.currentDate = new Date();
$scope.monthlyDate = new Date($scope.currentDate.getMonth('MM'))}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want an md-select rather than a md-datepicker. See example below.

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('exampleApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial'])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];
  }
  ExampleController.$inject = [];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <md-input-container>
    <md-select ng-model="vm.chosenMonth" placeholder="Select a month">
      <md-option ng-value="month" ng-repeat="month in vm.monthNames">{{ month }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks @ScottL, that's exactly what I did since `md-datepicker` has no attribute yet to choose and display month or year only. I tried using the `md-current-view="year"` but still the days are displayed after you click a month. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the datepicker, with the latest version. You can set `md-mode="month"` working demo below

```
<md-input-container flex="100" layout="column">
          <div style="font-size: 10px; color: blue;" label ng-bind="::dateFields[2].label"></div>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields.selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields.required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields.locale"
                     md-mode="month"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eV2Kmt?p=preview)**

Comment: I use the library for angular material  from CDN and it won't work. 
It seems that it only works with the library from formhero. why?

Comment: got it. further information https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9260

Comment: Sajeeth i have a query same like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584949/i-need-year-picker-using-material-design-or-how-to-turn-md-datepicker-in-to-only

Comment: It is working fine for me if I use the latest version of angular.min.js . But if I want day month year format means what can I do? It is not working.

Comment: why they have not documented it ?

Comment: and also if anyone want to change angular-material.js and css in your project source code, follow this commit and modify,
https://github.com/crisbeto/material/commit/303a7d2bdd3138c01675d3b528591e203834fc4d#diff-54335c1608494585213f0ea1fbe9e6a2L198

Comment: this feature is not in official angular material build, it was implelemted by contributer, in order to use it you need to use angular material from https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.js