# How to get a year datepicker in AngularJS Material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Are there any `md-year` pickers available? if yes, please share me some links. If no, then is it possible to turn a `md-datepicker` into a year picker?

I have tried with a normal one with giving modes, types of models etc but no useful output.

Answer (score 0):

[In the docs on `<md-datepicker>`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker), there is an option for a year picker by using the `md-current-view` attribute, setting it to either `year` or `month`:

```html
<md-datepicker
    md-current-view="year"
    ng-model="myCustomYearDate"
    md-placeholder="Enter Date">
</md-datepicker>
```

Comment: i tried this but i dint get what i am expecting....i want only years http://plnkr.co/edit/Eey5nlIiTYtiXSHZ6Luf?p=preview

Comment: @SaEChowdary Looks like `md-current-view` only came in version 1.1.0 and later. Update your angularjs-material to 1.1.0 and above

Comment: i am using md version 1.1.3 and your update have months with years...i need only rears

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such way to only show year view. [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714966/md-datepicker-view-should-display-the-months-only#answer-39716283)